# Increased loading times when accessing site without using www subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I've been running some loading time tests using tools.pingdom.com/fpt and noticed a huge difference between site.com and www.site.com

Without using www. when testing the site speed, we're getting a load time average of 2 to 4 seconds.

Using www. we're getting an average loading time of less than a second.

What is causing this, is this normal, and is there anything that I can do to make it load faster when a user doesn't enter the www portion of the domainname?

Edit: here's the results for the first part of the test when not using www:

```
dns: 280ms
connect: 284ms
send: 0ms
wait: 1.69s
receive: 0ms
```

When using www it's much faster:

```
dns: 0ms
connect: 4ms
send: 0ms
wait: 6ms
receive: 0ms
```

How would I go about determining what is causing the 1.69 second wait when not using the www?

Comment: additional DNS lookups?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I've added the relevant results from the test. There is a long wait time, and I'm not sure what would cause that, or how I would figure out the cause.

Comment: @rmmoul That's usually a delay caused by the webserver generating non-static content.  Is it possible that your code is causing content to be generated when accessed without the `www`, or you have some optimizations that apply differently, based on whether or not the `www` is used?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Using http://www.webpagetest.org/ to get a more detailed view, it looks like the non www request is getting redirecting to the www version and then taking a second or so to start sending data. Running it there with the www is near instant, with a wait of only a few ms. Could this be caused by the redirect, and is there any way to shorten this time if it is?

Comment: Could be, but I don't know.  You should edit your more detailed results into the post, and maybe someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Is it also possible the you always test "non-www" first, and that the "www" results are then cached and stuff? Can you try www first on your next test, and after that non-www?

Comment: @MichelZ This is a consistent repeatable affect, regardless of the order I try the tests in, or how many times I run the test.